# Using signal to pop-up a screen

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmainwindow

I'm having a little trouble using a signal to make a little screen appear.
Shortening all i have so far, this following code should show my problem.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 

class InformatieVenster(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Informatie')
        self.setGeometry(100,100,300,200)

informatie = InformatieVenster()  

class MenuKlasse(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        about = QtGui.QAction('About...', self)
        about.setShortcut('Ctrl+A')
        about.setStatusTip('Some text, haha')
        self.connect(about, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), QtCore.SIGNAL(informatie.show()))

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.Menu1 = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.Menu1.addAction(about)

Menu = MenuKlasse()
Venster = QtGui.QMainWindow() 
Venster.menuBar().addMenu(Menu.Menu1)
Venster.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300); 
size =  Venster.geometry()
Venster.show()
qApp.exec_()
```

When this program is runned, the 'informatie' window automatically pops-up.
However... i only want this to happen every time I click on 'about...' in the menu, or when i use the assigned shortcut.

How may i improve my code such that my problem will be made history?

Greets!

Answer (score 3):

The window is shown, because you are actually calling `.show()` during your connect.  You have to pass a function object, not the result of a function invocation, as argument to `.connect()`.  Moreover the function to be invoked, if a signal is emitted, is called "slot", the second `SIGNAL()` is completely misplaced.

Replace the connect line with:

```
self.connect(about, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()') informatie.show)
```

Even better, use the modern connection syntax:

```
about.triggered.connect(informatie.show)
```

Btw, do not use absolute sizes in GUI programs.  Instead use layout management.

Comment: QAction never emits a `"clicked()"` signal use `"triggered()"` instead.

Comment: about.triggered.connect(informatie.show)  works fine indeed. What should i do when i want it to work unlimited? Because in the current state it works fine ones, but when i try again it won't show the window.